# Some of the rows not displaying non-english characters in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, utf-8, oracle-sqldeveloper, nls-lang

The character set of the db is

> "WE8MSWIN1252"

and I am inserting the rows through a bat file where I set **"NLS_LANG"** to

> ".WE8MSWIN1252"

. At the end of the insertions, some of the rows in SQL Developer display a certain character while some not.

Comment: Check the value of NLS_LANG in SQL Developer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> some of the rows in SQL Developer display a certain character while some not.

It is a **display** issue with your **SQL Developer client**. Use proper value for the **NLS** settings in your SQL Developer.

Go to,

**`Tools --> Preferences --> NLS`**

[image]